# Is DiMaio's book "Gunshot Wounds" considered reliable?

Tags: gunshot-wounds

I'm doing some research on gunshot wounds for a tabletop role-playing game. I have Vincent DiMaio's book ***Gunshot Wounds: Practical Aspects of Firearms, Ballistics and Forensic Techniques***, third edition, and understand it reasonably well. However, I am not a professional in the field, and it agrees with the ideas I had before I bought it well enough to make me suspicious.

I can see from straightforward web searches that he's popularly regarded as an expert on the subject. The agreement of the book with my non-expert ideas is what made me wonder if he's *only* a popular expert, rather than an actual one.

Is this book considered a reliable guide to its subject matter?

Comment: What research have you done? The author is a widely recognized authority on the subject.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Added.